# Moving a SVG in react native too much to the left brings it back from the right instead of hiding it

Tags: react-native

So I'm trying to animate a cloud svg to come from the left of the screen and to go to the right. To do that I've set the left css property to -width of the svg. But instead of the svg being hidden, it comes from the right. Here's an example with - half the width:
[image: Image desxription]

The style props that I'm using are: `{ position: 'absolute', top: 70, left: -70 }`

How can I prevent it from coming out of the right side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `{ overflow: 'hidden' }` for element or parent View.

Or just try to change the x position of the SVG:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Svg,{
    Rect,
} from 'react-native-svg';

export default class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Svg
    width="200"
    height="60"
>
    <Rect
        x="-25"
        y="5"
        width="190"
        height="50"
        fill="rgb(0,0,255)"
        strokeWidth="3"
        stroke="rgb(0,0,0)"
    />
</Svg>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `{ overflow: 'hidden' }` on the parent worked like a charm - thanks!